# Complex SQL Subquery failing

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

So initially this query was taking `8 minutes` to return 1400 rows. I commented out the part of the original query that was causing the lag. An **EXPLAIN** sql revealed that the `lien_objet_contact table` has no index. I can not simply create an index as this is for work and that requires a migration. I believe that if I could write the query that brings in **TXT_POSTE_CONTACT** as a subquery I could speed it up.

The problem with the below approach is that it brings in all contacts. I only want contacts based on the **WHERE** clause below. So they must me attached to a `poste.strreference`. Basically this is a database filled with jobs and candidates. Each job has a contact, which you might call a hiring manager. I think this is more of an approach issue. I might me completely off on my attempt below. If so I am open to suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT poste.pkposte 
                AS 
                `COLONNE_NON_AFFICHEE`, 
                poste.strreference 
                AS `TXT_REFERENCE`, 
                lib_poste.strlangue1 
                AS `TXT_INTITULE`, 
                Group_concat(DISTINCT Concat(lib_u.strprenom, ' ', 
                lib_u.strnom))             AS 
                `TXT_POSTE_CHARGE_RECRUTEMENT`,
                (SELECT Group_concat(DISTINCT Concat(lib_contact.strprenom, ' ', lib_contact.strnom)) 
                  FROM poste p
                   LEFT JOIN lien_objet_contact lib_loc
                   ON p.pkposte = lib_loc.fkobjet
                   LEFT JOIN contact lib_contact 
                   ON lib_loc.fkcontact = lib_contact.pkcontact) AS  `TXT_POSTE_CONTACT`,
                -- Group_concat(DISTINCT Concat(lib_contact.strprenom, ' ', 
                -- lib_contact.strnom)) AS 
                -- `TXT_POSTE_CONTACT`, 
                lib_country.strlangue1 
                AS `TXT_PAYS`, 
                lib_state.strlangue1 
                AS `TXT_REGION`, 
                lib_city.strlangue1 
                AS `TXT_DEPARTEMENT_GEO`, 
                Concat(c.strprenom, ' ', c.strnom) 
                AS `Candidate`, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN c.imobiliteinterne = 1 THEN "yes" 
                  WHEN c.imobiliteinterne = 0 THEN "no" 
                end 
                AS `Internal_Candidate`, 
                Max(Date_format(sa_hired_date.dtdateaction, "%c/%e/%y")) 
                AS `TXT_EMBAUCHER`, 
                Date_format(hireInfo.dtdebut, "%c/%e/%y") 
                AS StartDate, 
                Source.strlangue1 
                AS TXT_PARTENAIRE_SOURCE 
FROM   poste 
       INNER JOIN r_texte_court lib_poste 
               ON poste.fklibintitule = lib_poste.pktextecourt 
       LEFT JOIN lien_utilisateur_objet lib_luo 
              ON poste.pkposte = lib_luo.fkobjet 
                 AND lib_luo.itypeobjet = 2 
       LEFT JOIN utilisateur lib_u 
              ON lib_luo.fkutilisateur = lib_u.pkutilisateur 
       -- LEFT JOIN lien_objet_contact lib_loc 
       --        ON poste.pkposte = lib_loc.fkobjet 
       --           AND lib_loc.itypeobjet = 2 
       --           AND lib_loc.strcontexte = 'descriptif/contact' 
       -- LEFT JOIN contact lib_contact 
       --        ON lib_loc.fkcontact = lib_contact.pkcontact 
       LEFT JOIN affectation aff 
              ON aff.fkposte = poste.pkposte 
                 AND aff.isuppr = 0 
       LEFT JOIN candidat c 
              ON c.pkcandidat = aff.fkcandidat 
       LEFT JOIN lien_objet_ref_1 lor1a 
              ON lor1a.fkobjet = poste.pkposte 
                 AND lor1a.itypeobjet = 2 
                 AND lor1a.strcontexte = 'descriptif/pays' 
       LEFT JOIN r_referentiel rr_country 
              ON lor1a.fkreferentiel = rr_country.pkreferentiel 
       LEFT JOIN r_libelle_ref lib_country 
              ON rr_country.fklib1 = lib_country.pklibelleref 
       LEFT JOIN lien_objet_ref_2 lor2a 
              ON lor2a.fkobjet = poste.pkposte 
                 AND lor2a.itypeobjet = 2 
                 AND lor2a.strcontexte = 'descriptif/region' 
       LEFT JOIN r_referentiel rr_state 
              ON lor2a.fkreferentiel = rr_state.pkreferentiel 
       LEFT JOIN r_libelle_ref lib_state 
              ON rr_state.fklib1 = lib_state.pklibelleref 
       LEFT JOIN lien_objet_ref_3 lor3a 
              ON lor3a.fkobjet = poste.pkposte 
                 AND lor3a.itypeobjet = 2 
                 AND lor3a.strcontexte = 'descriptif/departement_geo' 
       LEFT JOIN r_referentiel rr_city 
              ON lor3a.fkreferentiel = rr_city.pkreferentiel 
       LEFT JOIN r_libelle_ref lib_city 
              ON rr_city.fklib1 = lib_city.pklibelleref 
       LEFT JOIN historique_candidat sa_hired_date 
              ON c.pkcandidat = sa_hired_date.fkcandidat 
       LEFT JOIN embauche hireInfo 
              ON aff.pkaffectation = hireInfo.fkaffectation 
       INNER JOIN embauche hireInfoFilter 
               ON aff.pkaffectation = hireInfoFilter.fkaffectation 
       LEFT JOIN candidature cand 
              ON c.pkcandidat = cand.fkcandidat 
       LEFT JOIN partenaire pnaire 
              ON cand.fkpartenairesource = pnaire.pkpartenaire 
       LEFT JOIN r_texte_court Source 
              ON Source.pktextecourt = pnaire.fklibnom 
WHERE  poste.isuppr <> 1 
       AND poste.pkposte <> 1 
       AND hireInfo.iembauche = 1 
GROUP  BY `txt_reference`, 
          `pkcandidat`
```

Comment: Over 20 joins? I cannot read the language to know what tables may hold but consider combining tables, such as all jobs in one table with indicator columns. If not for efficiency, then maintainability. This is one of those cases where too much normalization may be the issue.

Comment: Please show your DDL including all indexes & EXPLAIN output.

Comment: In general, combining SELECT DISTINCT with GROUP BY is a bit suspicious. (Can be needed once in a while, but most of time there's something wrong.)

Comment: ...and, to extend what @jarlh observes, `SELECT DISTINCT`, if it is not actually needed, can be a performance killer since the server has to do extra work to compare all the rows for uniqueness even though non-uniqueness is impossible, as should be the case with the `GROUP BY`, here.  `DISTINCT` should not be used with out specific justification.